# mysqldump concurrency

Tags: concurrency, mysql

if I started mysqldump on a database, and then created a new table with new data, will this table be dumped?  what's the concurrency behavior here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is not sure, from [Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction):

> > --single-transaction
>
> This option sends a START TRANSACTION
>   SQL statement to the server before
>   dumping data. It is useful only with
>   transactional tables such as InnoDB
>   and BDB, because then it dumps the
>   consistent state of the database at
>   the time when BEGIN was issued without
>   blocking any applications.
>
> When using this option, you should
>   keep in mind that only InnoDB tables
>   are dumped in a consistent state. For
>   example, any MyISAM or MEMORY tables
>   dumped while using this option may
>   still change state.
>
> While a --single-transaction dump is
>   in process, to ensure a valid dump
>   file (correct table contents and
>   binary log coordinates), no other
>   connection should use the following
>   statements: ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE,
>   DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE
>   TABLE. A consistent read is not
>   isolated from those statements, so use
>   of them on a table to be dumped can
>   cause the SELECT that is performed by
>   mysqldump to retrieve the table
>   contents to obtain incorrect contents
>   or fail.
>
> The --single-transaction option and
>   the --lock-tables option are mutually
>   exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes
>   any pending transactions to be
>   committed implicitly.
>
> This option is not supported for MySQL
>   Cluster tables; the results cannot be
>   guaranteed to be consistent due to the
>   fact that the NDBCLUSTER storage
>   engine supports only the
>   READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation
>   level. You should always use NDB
>   backup and restore instead.
>
> To dump large tables, you should
>   combine the --single-transaction
>   option with --quick.

If you want to backup/move your live DB, you should consider [MySQL replication](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-move-copy-a-live-mysql-database-and-what-1257.html)